# Calling a PHP file doubles the amount of requests sent with every click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having an issue which is causing a lot of lag on my website because of the number of calls being made when it should only make one.

So I have a PHP file that displays the name of a load of notes from a database.

This file is `general_notes.php`:

```
<div class="main-container-notes">
    <div id="left-box">
        <?php 

        echo "<div style='width: 100%;'>";

        // while ( $notename = "Excel Registers")
        while ( $noteName = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $resultNotes, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
        {
            echo "<div class='hvr-bounce-to-right1 hover-cursor output noSelect' data-noteid='{$noteName['NoteID']}' style='width: 100%; border-right: 5px solid #00AA88; height: 50px;'>" . $noteName['NoteName'] . "</div>";
        }

        echo "</div>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div id="right-box">
       <?php 

       if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true)  
       {
            // include 'noteContent.php'; 
       }

       ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

you'll see in the echo the div has a class of "output". This is then used here in `scripts.js`:

```
$(".output").click(function () 
    {
        var noteid = $(this).data("noteid");
        var templatenoteid = $(this).data("templatenoteid");
        var variablenoteid = $(this).data("variablenoteid");
        console.log(noteid);

        if ($(this).data("noteid")) 
        {
            $("#right-box").load("noteContent.php", {noteid: noteid});
        }

        else if ($(this).data("templatenoteid")) 
        {
            $("#right-box").load("templateNoteContent.php", {templatenoteid: templatenoteid});
        }

        else
        {
            $("#right-box").load("variableContent.php", {variablenoteid: variablenoteid});
        }
    });
```

So when that is clicked it will display the content of that note in the right hand box using this php file `noteContent.php`:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        $showNoteInfo = "SELECT Note, NoteName FROM Notes WHERE NoteID = " . $_POST['noteid'];
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $showNoteInfo);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['noteid'])) 
    {
        if (empty($_POST['noteid'])) 
        {
            $notes = 'No Data';
        }
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) 
        {
            $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<div class='custom-font title-container'>
                    <div class='expand-button-container fa fa-expand' onclick='expandWindow()'></div>
                    <div id='title-container1'><div class='edit-note fa fa-pencil' onclick='editGeneralNote()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" . $data['NoteName'] . "&nbsp;<div class='save-note fa fa-thumbs-up' onclick='saveGeneralNote(); submitNoteText();'></div></div>
                  </div>";
            echo "<textarea spellcheck='false' readonly id='ta1'>" . $data['Note'] . "</textarea>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No data found";
        }
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

function submitNoteText()
{
    var noteid = <?php if(isset($_POST['noteid'])){ echo $_POST['noteid'];} ?>;
    var notetext = $("#ta1").val();
    var data = {noteid1: noteid, notetext1: notetext};

    if(noteid == ''||notetext == '')
    {
        alert("NoteID or Text is blank");
    }
    else
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "submitNoteText.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
};

</script>
```

However every time I click to display a note, it displays it and makes this call: [image]

However I click again and it doubles the amount of times it makes that call.

By the 7th click it has made 64 calls to `noteContent.php`[image]

Why is it doubling the amount of calls to `noteContent.php` everytime I click on a note name?

PS. I apologise if this isn't worded the best it could be, I wasn't sure how to explain what was happening which also makes it difficult to search for a solution when I'm not sure what to search for.

Comment: Waaaaay too much code there for us to go through and identify the issue. You need to produce a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: what does saveGeneralNote() do? That appears to run at the same time as saveNoteText()

Comment: Yeah, apologies, i'm having trouble narrowing it down myself because i don't want to not include something that code be the issue, i'll try and see if i can minimize it.

Comment: @user7409253 With something like this look at JavaScript bindings, particularly any that are generated when you click to display a note. You'll probably find you are binding to existing elements multiple times.

Comment: @ADyson it simply changes the text area that the note content is displayed in from coloured to non coloured and from an editable text area to non editable 
function saveGeneralNote()
{
    $('#ta1').attr('readonly', true);
    $('#ta1').css('background-color', 'rgba(255, 169, 97, 0.2');
};

Comment: This kind of thing happens if you have an event binding inside an event handler, or if the AJAX call loads a `<script>` that adds the same event binding.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an event binding issue. It could be that the event binding is occurring more than once (i.e. multiple events are bound to the same element). To avoid this, consider using event delegation and calling `.off()` before you create the binding. See below:

```
$(".main-container-notes").off('click.note-click').on('click.note-click', '.output', function () 
    ...
    // Other Code
    ...
});
```

Note the `.note-click` next to the `click` event. This is an event namespace. jQuery allows you to provide event namespaces so that you can remove the specific event without for instance removing all attached `click` events. This is helpful if you have multiple plugins or code snippets assigning events. It prevents you from colliding with other functionality.

**Reference:** [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Ah ok, i'll give this a go and work this into my code! Thanks for the info too.

Comment: @user7409253 No problem, happy to help. I can't guarantee this will work but it's my initial guess based on the code you provided. If this doesn't work, let me know and I can modify it once we have more information.

Comment: Hi, i've just used that code you provided and it hasn't changed anything it still gradually doubles the amount of calls. Was there something i should fo with ".main-container-notes" as there is no class by this name in my code currently?

Comment: Don't worry i know where the main-container is now, shows how often i check my classes... xD however unfortunately it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

So i just thought i would update this as it could be helpful to someone else.

**Short story:**
In *noteContent.php* i had `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>`

Once i un-commented that out, it no longer doubled the requests.

**Reason i believe why that is:**
I still don't know for sure, but i believe its because in *scripts.js* when it makes the call to .load() *noteContent.php* it was reading that php file and seeing the link to *scripts.js* and reading it again!

However in my file general_notes.php (which is the file that *noteContent.php* is loaded into there is already a scripts.js reference therefore  its not needed in *noteContent.php* as well.)

Im still learning myself so i apologise for the lack of terminology and knowledge, but hopefully this can help someone else who is loading a php file with a script link into another php file that also has a script link. You only need one! :)